# OpenGeo Suite 3.1 doesn't work anymore when setting up Client SDK 3.0.2

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, geoext, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

We've installed OpenGeo Suite 3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and everything works fine.

When trying to set up the OpenGeo Client SDK 3.0.2 (following http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/apps/clientsdk.html), however, the OpenGeo Suite doesn't work anymore. 
After inserting the SDK in PATH and adding ANT_HOME and JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment, tomcat6 starts up, but doesn't serve anything in the browser anymore.

The severe error in the log looks as follows:

```
24 Jul 15:35:24 WARN [config.CustomEditorConfigurer] - Passing PropertyEditor instances into CustomEditorConfigurer is deprecated: use PropertyEditorRegistrars or PropertyEditor class names instead. Offending key [org.geotools.util.Version; offending editor instance: org.geoserver.platform.util.VersionPropertyEditor@3f705316

24.07.2013 15:35:24 org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
SCHWERWIEGEND: Extension lookup occured, but ApplicationContext is unset.

24 Jul 15:35:24 ERROR [geoserver.global] -
- GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR: /usr/share/opengeo-suite-data/geoserver_data
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Are there conflicts between the versions? A new SDK doesn't seem to exist yet.

EDIT: The error from the log doesn't seem to have to do anything with our problem, since it is also logged in another working geoserver environment.

Comment: OK we solved our issue. The problem was that the server's IP was kicked out of the iptables upon reboot after modifying the PATH. In addition we didn't put ./ in front of "suite-sdk create path/to/myapp" when running the script in bin, so the command wasn't found. Still learning on Linux... thanks for the quick reaction!

Comment: Ok, but you should definitely not set JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, you only need to set the `PATH` for the `suite-sdk` binary. Do not set `JAVA_HOME` and `ANT_HOME`, these are taking care of already.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. We had tried this before, but if we don't set ANT_HOME we cannot run "suite-sdk create path/to/myapp", because the command is not found.